# Sharekit2.0 could not post together "URL-linked text, image" information to facebook wall

Tags: facebook, sharekit

I'm upgrading from old sharekit to latest Sharekit2.0.

Ultimately I need to reach this on Facebookshare: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/eight29/demo.png

In old sharekit, I can do that by  dialog.attachment  (FBStreamDialog) as shown as below. However, in latest version, this function is missing.

```
BStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
        dialog.delegate = self;
        dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Post Item to Facebook";
        dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"example\",\"href\":\"http://apps.facebook.com/example/?%d\",\
```

How can make it?

Thanks!

Liang

Answer (score 1):

FBStreamDialog is not technically a part of ShareKit, but it belongs to Facebook-ios-sdk, which happens to be used in ShareKit.

FBStreamDialog no longer exists in FB's sdk, and other FBDialog family classes are deprecated. I suggest you to use [their graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), check "publishing" section for all possible parameters. Hopefully some will suit your purpose.

As for implementation, check SHKFacebook's `- (void)doSend` method. You can then subclass SHKFacebook and implement your own.